# On integration, measurability, almost everywhere concept

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification

**I have updated considerably, with my full solution. Feedback appreciated!**

Suppose $f$ is a nonnegative, measurable function and $\int f d\mu < \infty.$ Let $$h(w)=\begin{cases}f(w) \ \ \ \text{if} \ \ f(w)\in \mathbb{R} \\ \\ 0 \ \ \ \text{if} \ \ \ f(w)=\infty\end{cases}$$
Show that $h$ is measurable and $\int f d\mu = \int h d\mu.$

**Attempt:**

Suppose $\int f d\mu < \infty.$ Let $A_1 = \{w \in \Omega:f(w)\neq h(w)\}$ and $A_2 = \{w \in \Omega:f(w) = h(w)\}.$ Then $A_1$ and $A_2$ form a finite measurable partition of $\Omega$. So

$$\infty>\int f d \mu=\sup\sum\limits_{i=1}^2\left[\inf\limits_{w \in A_i} f(w)\right]\mu(A_i) \geq \sup\left[\inf\limits_{w \in A_1} f(w)\right]\mu(A_1).$$

So $\sup\left[\inf\limits_{w \in A_1} f(w)\right]\mu(A_1)<\infty.$ But $f(w)=\infty$ for $w \in A_1$. So $\inf\limits_{w \in A_1}f(w)=\infty.$

So $\mu(A_1)$ must be $0$.

By the result that $$\int f d \mu<\infty \Rightarrow f \text{ is finite a.e.} \iff \mu\left(\{w \in \Omega:f(w)=\infty\}\right)=0,$$ we have that $f$ is finite a.e. and thus $f=h$ a.e.

**Claim:** $h$ is measurable.

**Proof:** $\forall \alpha \geq 0, \{w:h(w)>\alpha\}=\{w:f(w)>\alpha, w \in \mathbb{R}\}.$ Thus $\{w:h(w)>\alpha\}$ is measurable for $\alpha \geq 0$.

$\forall \alpha < 0, \{w:h(w)>\alpha\}=\{w:f(w)>\alpha, w \in \mathbb{R}\} \cup \{w:w \notin \mathbb{R}\}.$ However, the first term on the right is measurable (because $f$ is measurable), and the second term is $w \in \mathbb{R}^c$, which is $\varnothing$, which is measurable. Thus $\{w:h(w)>\alpha\}$ is measurable for $\alpha < 0$.

Thus $h$ is measurable.

By a prior fact that $f=0$ a.e. iff $\int f d \mu=0$, we have that $f=h$ a.e. implies $f-h=0$ a.e. implies $\int(f-h)d \mu=0.$ Hence $\int f d\mu=\int h d\mu.$

Is the work above OK?

Comment: Consider the set of $\omega$ for which $f(\omega)\neq h(\omega)$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: The above seems correct! To add to Eric's hint: what is the measure of the set he describes?

Comment: @EricStucky Please see edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Consider the set of $\omega$ for which $f(\omega)\neq h(\omega)$. Can you take it from here?

The work you did before the update is perfect. The work you did after the update looks alright; in particular it is fine after you conclude that $f(\omega)=h(\omega)$ a.e. But unfortunately I cannot read what is going on in the paragraph before it: the notation looks a little off to me.

Comment: @arabhimanachra: No, I'm talking about the part where you argue $f=h$ a.e. using the definition of the integral